# Evaluate $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{n^3+1}$ if it can express in terms of elementary functions.

Tags: functions

Evaluate $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{n^3+1}$ if it can express in terms of elementary functions .

You may refer to [this](http://tw.group.knowledge.yahoo.com/math-etm/article/view?aid=140) and [this](http://tw.group.knowledge.yahoo.com/math-etm/article/view?aid=139) articles.

Comment: @kahen: The imperative is just a grammatical form. We use it in proofs all the time; nothing rude about that. What _is_ rude is the OP just posting an exercise text without adding anything of his own. This is independent of the grammar used in the exercise text.

Comment: 1.6865 http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+1%2F%28n%5E3%2B1%29 I have no clue what they did there, I dunno what digamma functions are. It seems that its a sort of derivative of the gamma function, but I fail to see how they got there. Might help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use $n^3+1 = (n+1)(n^2-n+1) = (n+1)(n-\omega)(n - \bar{\omega})$, where $\omega = \mathrm{e}^{i \pi/3}$. Then
$$
   \frac{1}{n^3+1} = \frac{1}{3} \frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{3} \frac{\omega}{n -\omega} - \frac{1}{3} \frac{\bar{\omega}}{n -\bar{\omega}} = \frac{1}{3} \frac{\omega +\bar{\omega}}{n+1} - \frac{1}{3} \frac{\omega}{n -\omega} - \frac{1}{3} \frac{\bar{\omega}}{n -\bar{\omega}}
$$
Therefore
$$
  \sum_{n=0}^m \frac{1}{n^3+1} = \frac{\omega}{3} \sum_{n=0}^m \left(\frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{n-\omega}  \right) + \frac{\bar{\omega}}{3} \sum_{n=0}^m \left(\frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{n-\bar{\omega}}  \right)
$$
Thus
$$
 \begin{eqnarray}
  \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3+1} &=& \frac{\omega}{3} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{n-\omega}  \right) + \frac{\bar{\omega}}{3} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{n-\bar{\omega}}  \right) \\
  &=& \frac{\omega}{3} \left( \gamma + \psi(-\omega) \right) + \frac{\bar{\omega}}{3} \left( \gamma + \psi(-\bar{\omega}) \right)
\end{eqnarray}
$$
where $\psi(x)$ is the [digamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function), and $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant).

Thus the sum is not elementary.

Comment: The sum has a non-elementary expression but it does not really mean that it cannot be expressed elementary...

Comment: Is this generally true -- if you change the denominator to $n^{k}+1$, is it true that the sum is $\frac{e^{\pi i /k}}{k}\left(\gamma+\psi(-e^{\pi i /k})\right)+ \frac{e^{-\pi i /k}}{k}\left(\gamma+\psi(-e^{-\pi i /k})\right)$?

Comment: @deoxygerbe No, we should sum over roots of $n^k + 1$.